# Finding the Minimum of an Array List Using Recursive Functions

Tags: java, recursion

[Part 1 of the given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT8QI.png)
[Part 2 of the given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSFVJ.png)

The only part that can be changed is lines 29-39. The comments were already given as instructions and the method signature for findMinimum needs to remain the same as it already is. The instructions for the assignment are on the right side of the Part 1 image.

The only line I need help changing in line 39, I don't understand how to format the recursion.

How can I make a recursive statement that removes the last value in the list while looking for the minimum, when the parameters for the method only call for an ArrayList?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If I remove the error will that help you solve it? If it will then I can remove it and upload again.

Comment: [Please do not ask people to do your homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) . I mean atleast try a little bit solving the issue yourself and then you can ask questions.

Comment: I did I tried solving it but I do not understand how to do the recursive portion, how do I make sure my recursive call is not infinite because the method only takes the array list as a parameter.

Comment: Post the code you tried and then explain which exact part is not working.

Comment: "how do I make sure my recursive call is not infinite" When the instructor was teaching you about recursion, do you remember hearing the words "base case"? Can you think of one that applies to this situation?

Comment: The code I added is in lines 29-39, and line 39 is not working because it is not the correct parameter for the function. But If I only enter an array list then I get a different infinite error.

Comment: I added the base case, and I think it is right because it makes sense right now, but I am still confused about the recursive portion.

Comment: @AlexRudenko could you elaborate on that tehcnique, could you show me an example. Also I don't think the ArrayList would be empty because the base case exits the loop once the size of the list is = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fix should work:

```java
    return Math.min(numbers.get(amount - 1), findMin(numbers.subList(0, amount - 1)));
```

It may be possible to use [`List::remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) too as this method returns the removed element:

```java
    // remove the last element and then check the remainder, input array is cleared finally
    return Math.min(numbers.remove(amount - 1), findMin(numbers));
```